# SPARQL - how to get individual data property from linked individual

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I build this ontology in protege. I have this individual `ev001` that has these types `Room`,`hasRoom only {rm001}` and `rm001` has data property `roomName "room 1"^^xsd:string`.

Right now I have a SPARQL query that returns

```
Event     Room     RoomName
ev001     {rm001}
```

My question is, how to get the room name from there,
here is my query so far

```
SELECT ?event ?room ?roomname
WHERE { ?x owl:onProperty base:hasRoom .
        ?event a base:FilmScreening ;
                   a ?x .
        ?x owl:allValuesFrom ?room .
}
```

Any advice is appreciated, thank you very much

Comment: Is it a restriction with `owl:allValuesFrom` and a singleton nominal (aka `owl:oneOf`) or with `owl:hasValue`? For the first case, it would be a collection and you would have to parse rdf:lists first. For the second case it should be simply as @JoshuaTaylor has shown below.

Comment: I think it is the first case as you said. So how do i proceed from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it looks like you'd just need:

```sql
SELECT ?event ?room ?roomname
WHERE {
  ?event base:hasRoom ?room .
  ?room base:roomName ?roomname. 
}
```

You don't need to be retrieving all the axiom stuff with owl:onProperty, etc.  However, in your case, the ontology is structured a bit strangely.  E.g., you have content like:

```xml
<!-- http://www.example.org/ontologies/loncon3#pi00314001 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.org/ontologies/loncon3#pi00314001">
    <!-- ... -->
    <rdf:type>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ontologies/loncon3#hasRoom"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.org/ontologies/loncon3#rm03005"/>
                    </owl:oneOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </owl:allValuesFrom>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdf:type>
    <!-- ... -->
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

In the Manchester syntax, that says that pi00314001 has the type:

hasRoom only { rm03005 }

Based on your question, it sounds like you expect the

pi00314001 hasRoom rm03005

is in your data, or at least inferable from it.  Unfortunately, that's not what it actually means.  When you say that an individual **X** has the type

**p only D**

it means it *if* **X** has any value for the property **p**, then that value must be an instance of **D**.  Similarly, the content in your ontology says that *if* pi00314001 has a value for the property hasRoom, then that value must be from the class { rm03005 }.  It *doesn't* say that pi00314001 actually *has* a value for that property, so you don't actually know whether it has rm03005 as a value for hasRoom or not.

If it's under your control, I think you'd want to add some actual object property assertions to your ontology, so that the query I mentioned above will work.  Right now your ontology is telling you more about what's *possible* than what's actually the case.

That said, if you do want to retrieve the room from the data as it's structured now, you can follow the structure of the data and make that work too.  It'd be something like:

```sql
select ?event ?roomName {
  ?event a [ owl:onProperty base:hasRoom ;
             owl:allValuesFrom/owl:oneOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?room ] .
  ?room base:roomName ?roomName .
}
```

Comment: its not working, do you think there's something wrong with the ontology?
`hasRoom` is an object property that has domain `Event` and has range `Room` if its help

Comment: Where I wrote ?x, it should be ?event.

Comment: Without seeing your actual data though, it will be hard to debug any more than this.

Comment: this is the complete file, please have a look if you have time to spare.
https://gist.github.com/ariestikto/554c559ba9cf0500f7a39e15a2e25cab
thank you very much.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think the nominal is contained in a collection as it's not used `owl:hasValue` but the equivalent consisting of `owl:allValuesFrom` and a singleton of `owl:oneOf` which uses collections.

Comment: @AKSW Yes, I was hoping that OP was focusing on the types rather than the actual object property assertions.  Looking at the ontology, it appears that the types are all that are there.  And that means that the ontology never actually says that the event has a particular room, just that *if* it has a room, what room it would have to be.

Comment: @ariestikto I've updated my answer;  the query I gave won't work, because the ontology doesn't actually state quite what it sounds like you want it to.  The ontology says that *if* ev001 has a room, then the room must be rm001;  it doesn't actually say that ev001 has that room.  if that's what you expected, then you can still write a query that will retrieve it, but first let's confirm whether that's what you want or not.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor ah right, its exactly as you said.
thank you for your explanation.

one more question though, is it possible to do it if the object property assertions is inferred from the types? or should i insert all of it?

Comment: @ariestikto as written, the ontology is basically saying "if the event has a room, it would be this room".  You can retrieve that with a SPARQL query. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I got it, so I have to add the object property assertions so the query would work. Thank you very much.